# jquery wildcard selector - index of form element array

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, element, wildcard

I've got a form with several multi-dimensional names. I am using the jquery *= selector to pick-out groups on them and perform functions when they change. I am trying to figure out how to get the individual array indexes of the form element name.

I want to be able to identify the doorID by it's individual array 'parts'. e.g door_6x7, or 0 for `opening[door_6x7][0]`

JQUERY:

```
    $("select[name*=door_6x]").change(function() {

        var doorID = $(this).attr("name");
            alert(doorID);

    });
```

SAMPLE HTML:

```
                  <td width="50"><select name="opening[door_6x7][0]">
                      <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select></td>
                  <td width="50"><select name="opening[door_6x7][1]">
                      <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select></td>
                  <td width="50"><select name="opening[door_6x7][2]">
                      <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                      <option value="6">6</option>
                    </select></td>
                  <td width="50"><select name="opening[door_6x7][3]">
                      <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                      <option value="6">6</option>
                    </select></td>
```

Comment: interesting... I never even knew this is possible... would like to see an answer for it, too :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
 $("select[name*=door_6x]").change(function() {

    var doorID = $(this).attr("name");
    var x = doorID.match(/\[[0-9]+\]/i);

    alert(x[0].match(/[0-9]+/i));

});
```

Comment: the regex works good to parse it manaully. I was hoping there was a way to treat the name as an array so I could reference opening[0] would be 'door_6x7' and opening[1] would be '0'. Maybe I'm just thinking about it the wrong way.

Comment: Why don't you use a rel attribute and then just read the rel? I usually do it like that..